# How to transpose a column as column title with duplicated rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this

| Index | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | type1 | name1 | true |
| 3 | type1 | name2 | false |
| 3 | type2 | name3 | false |
| 3 | type2 | name3 | false |
| 3 | type1 | name2 | false |

and I want it to look like this

| type1 | type2 | Column D | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | NAN | true | 1 |
| name2 | name3 | false | 3 |
| name2 | name3 | false | 3 |

I've tried pivot but I can't seem to get to the result I want. I ended up getting something like this.

```
          column c                    column d
```

type       type1       type2        type1     type2
index
1
2

Other solutions I've tried, like set_index().unstack(), don't work because I have duplicated rows and I need to keep them.
I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) but my values are not numeric and those answers, although helpful, do not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can first pivot the data frame based on the values of column B and then bring back the column D data by grouping the original data frame by index and taking the maximum value.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create your initial DataFrame
data = {
    'Index': [1, 3, 3],
    'Column B': ['type1', 'type1', 'type2'],
    'Column C': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
    'Column D': [True, False, False]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Pivot the DataFrame while preserving duplicate rows
df_pivoted = df.pivot(index='Index', columns='Column B', values='Column C')

# Reset the index to bring 'Index' back as a column
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.reset_index()

# Merge the original 'Column D' back into the pivoted DataFrame
df_pivoted['Column D'] = df.groupby('Index')['Column D'].max().reset_index(drop=True)

# Rename the columns
df_pivoted.columns.name = None
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.rename(columns={'Index': 'Index'})

# Fill NaN values in the pivot table with 'NAN'
df_pivoted = df_pivoted.fillna('NAN')

# Reorder the columns as needed
df_pivoted = df_pivoted[['type1', 'type2', 'Column D', 'Index']]

print(df_pivoted)
```

Output:

|  | type1 | type2 | Column D | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | NAN | True | 1 |
| 1 | name2 | name3 | False | 3 |

Comment: It can not be reshaped with duplicated index. (''ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'')

Comment: For me it runs fine

Comment: I forgot a detail on the table example. My table has duplicated rows, that makes this solution not work